# Create custom component in c++/cli

Tags: .net, visual-studio, user-interface, c++-cli

I want to create my own button, which can be template, because I want to create several buttons in my app. Besides button properties in my template I want to have events.

I create component class:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


namespace myApp {

    public ref class GoButton :  public System::Windows::Forms::Button
    {
    public:
        GoButton(int x, int y)
        {
            InitializeComponent(x, y);
        }

    protected:
        ~GoButton()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button;
    protected:

    protected:

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(int x, int y)
        {
            this->button = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button
            // 
            this->button->FlatStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FlatStyle::Flat;
            this->button->Location = System::Drawing::Point(x, y);
            this->button->Name = L"button";
            this->button->Size = System::Drawing::Size(169, 44);
            this->button->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button->Text = L"button";
            this->button->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button->MouseLeave += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &GoButton::button_MouseLeave);
            this->button->MouseMove += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &GoButton::button_MouseMove);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
    {
        this->BackgroundImage = Drawing::Image::FromFile("b2.png");
    }
    private: System::Void button_MouseLeave(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        this->BackgroundImage = Drawing::Image::FromFile("b.png");
    }
    };
}
```

After that, I create main window and try to add this button:
header:

```
#pragma once

#include "GoButton.h"

namespace myApp {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class MainWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MainWindow(void);

    protected:
        ~MainWindow();

    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void);
#pragma endregion

    };
}
```

cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

namespace myApp
{
    MainWindow::MainWindow(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

    void MainWindow::InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        //this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button1 = (gcnew GoButton(-1, 50));
        this->SuspendLayout();

        // MainWindow
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(546, 405);
        this->Location = System::Drawing::Point(37, 162);
        this->Name = L"MainWindow";
        this->Text = L"MainWindow";
    this->Controls->Add(button1);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }

}
```

The button does not appear with that properties that I set in GoButton class, how can I do what I want?

And in form builder, when I trying to open mainwindow I have an error that says: Can't find type GoButton

Comment: You've learned yourself some very bad habits that will get you into an enormous amount of trouble.  The button doesn't appear because you forgot to add it to the form's Controls collection.  After you fixed that you'll see it but it won't work.  Really rather best to spend some time learning Winforms basics.

Comment: @HansPassant ah, okay i add it, when past code here delete this line, help me please..

Comment: @HansPassant on what specific habits are you talking about ?

Comment: @HansPassant omg, very good help